# Notepad++ visibility for BOM

Tags: notepad++, vi

How to use the 6.2.3 version of Notepad++.I want to know how to make visible of BOM chanracters.I tried with menu list available but no use.

But those characters are available only at Linux Environment.If we use vi editor.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/feature-requests/2522/

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what you want to achieve so this may be irrelevant, but you could always use a hex editor to see and edit the raw representation of your file.

Comment: There is the *HEX-Editor* plugin for Notepad++.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, you can't show/visualize the BOM in Notepad++.

The menu `View` > `Show Symbol` > `Show All Characters` doesn't include the `0xFEFF` character.

Answer (score 3):

Following up from  Abdull's comment above was able to view `ff fe` or `ÿþ` as the Unicode big endian (BE) byte order mark in the N++ hex plugin for N++ (v6.88). Once the plugin is installed click *Plugins > View in Hex*.

Comment: As a side note you should be looking for ef bb bf (characters ï»¿) in UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

> [vim](http://www.vim.org/) (in either textual or graphic mode) can show all control characters if you `:set list`.  The BOM is a special case, controlled by the `:set bomb` or `:set nobomb` commands.

*Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526881/text-editor-capable-of-viewing-invisibles/2574861#2574861), thank you Alex Martelli.*

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). I've fixed the quoting for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is for whoever is trying to find these annoying characters and filter em out.

In between the parenthesis there are 10 BOM charaters (aka 0xFEFF [e2 80 8b] \xEF\xBB\xBF) and this image shows how to find them.

In n++ Find: \u200b

[image: How to find the BOM characters]